# Animating on hover and having the animation freeze when it finishes in CSS

Tags: css, animation

I have an onhover animation for a div called logo. I want the logo to tilt when the mouse is hovered over. However, I don't want the logo to go back to it's original state when the animation is finished, until someone moves their mouse out of the element (mouse out).

```
#logo:hover{
    -webkit-animation-name:logorotate;
    animation-name:logorotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes logorotate{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the hover to *have* a state, and that when someone hovers the change is smooth, that is a transition and not an animation

```
#logo{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#logo:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#logo.mousein{
    -webkit-animation-name:logorotate;
    animation-name:logorotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes logorotate{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
```

then add following jquery:

```
$(document).read(function(){
     $("#logo").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("mousein");
     });

});
```

(Havn't tested the code yet, but schould work)